# Can't login as root on Linux and due to this I now can't restart the PC

Tags: 16.04, root, login-screen, services

I setup Teamviewer 12 to start as a daemon so I could restart and login as root, however when I loged in as root it looks like Linux got stuck and I can't do anything, i'm not at my PC right now and I can't restart my PC manually, but i can still access my PC from Teamviwer, I can't use shortcuts to open the terminal or anything, I can't press ctrl+alt+delete because that just causes my windows 10 host PC to do it, how can I fix this? I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: Can you hit ctrl+alt+f1?

Comment: Can you log in with `ssh` ?

Comment: @don.joey Nope, that does nothing

Comment: @SorenA I never setup ssh unfortunately :( i definitely will when i get back to my computer or fix this though

Comment: Can't you just close your teamviewer session?

Comment: @don.joey yeah but then i just go onto my laptop? I'm not stuck in the session with it but i don't want t wait a few days so i can get back to my PC to be able to use it.